# jQuery .animate() sets display:none, how to avoid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
    Click me  :-)
</div>

<div id="info" style="background:red; width:100%; height:100px; margin-bottom:-100px; z-index:20; position:absolute; bottom:0px;">
  Stay, damn!
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#info').animate({
        marginBottom: 'toggle'
    },{
        duration:500
    });
});
```

It's also available at http://jsfiddle.net/DxnQJ/

Obviously, I want the `#info DIV` to appear/disappear whenever the `#clickme DIV` is clicked. It's working as intended, except that the `#info DIV` disappears after the animation due to jQuery setting its CSS `display` property to `none`.

How can I tell jQuery to stop hiding my `DIV`?

Comment: Checking out jQuery source, it looks like 'toggle' was designed for effects that are either entirely shown or hidden (like height, width, and opacity).  
What happens is that clicking 'Click me :-)' and animating something not hidden for the first time has the same effect as if you had `marginBottom: 'hide'`. So when it is done animating, `jQuery( elem ).hide();` is called on your element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using `.slideToggle`:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#info').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/DxnQJ/2

Answer (score 3):

javascript code

```
 $('#clickme').toggle(
        function () {
            $('#info').animate({
                height:"0px"
            }, 500);
        },
        function () {
            $('#info').animate({
                height:"100px"
            }, 500);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/zymUK/2/

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your click function with this works:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
        var whichSetting = $('#info').css('marginBottom');
        if(whichSetting == '-100px') {
             whichSetting = '0px';  
        }
        else {
             whichSetting = '-100px';  
        }
        $('#info').animate({
            marginBottom: whichSetting
            },{
                duration:500
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's the down vote for? It may not be as elegant as the .slideToggle solution, but it works just fine. And it makes it work with marginBottom, which is what the poster had.